# How do I determine the size of a registry value's data using the Windows API?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, registry

`RegQueryValueEx()` basically requires you to take a wild guess at the size of the buffer you need to hold the registry value. If you mess it up, you get `ERROR_MORE_DATA` for your troubles. You could obviously just call the function in a loop and increase the buffer size every time until you get lucky but that "solution" makes me nauseous. Am I missing a way to do it properly or is the API really as bad as it seems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [RegQueryValueEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation says:

> If lpData is NULL, and lpcbData is non-NULL, the function returns
>   ERROR_SUCCESS and stores the size of the data, in bytes, in the
>   variable pointed to by lpcbData. This enables an application to
>   determine the best way to allocate a buffer for the value's data.

In other words, just specify NULL as the buffer, and the function can return the data size in the lpcbData.

So you just have to call the API twice, once to get the size, and once to get the actual data. This method is not uncommon in Windows APIs, by the way.

Comment: Ah. A simple case of reading comprehension failure. Thank you. :)

Comment: Note that in the case of strings a) the size is in bytes, not characters, and b) strings aren't guaranteed to be null-terminated, so you should always include an additional character for termination.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: If you use the newer [`RegGetValue()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724868.aspx) function instead, it will ensure string data is always null-terminated.

Comment: Why would you include an extra character for termination? At least in C++, you're going to pass the length and pointer to `std::string`, and it doesn't need that terminator when you've got the length. (In fact, passing the length explicitly is more efficient)

Comment: @MSalters: it's still messy, because you have to check whether or not the length you've been given includes the terminator or not.